# Adding CSV values together and updating the file with the sum?

Tags: python, csv

As an example in a CSV format, I have 20,3,1 printed.

In this case there are:

- 20 seats available
- 3 reservations
- 1 cancellation

I need to subtract the second value from the first one, and then add the third value to that, making a total. Then outputted as: 20,3,1,18 The sum being 18. This is just an example as there will be different files with different numbers, yet in this same formatting, from different files all named the same.
'The code so far is:

```
import csv

with open ('transactions.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print (readCSV)

for row in readCSV:
    print(row)
```

The CSV files will contain multiple rows of this formatting:

30,3,2

20,4,1

15,5,3

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I'd advise looking at the pandas library to be able to do it easily.

Comment: please share your attempts.

Comment: I currently have the file imported and printed.

Comment: import csv

with open ('transactions.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print (readCSV)
          
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add relevant code and other information.

Comment: This is for an assignment, just need to be able to compute the sum of those values for test cases, as required for the assignment.

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to your [identical code 3 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254744/trying-to-add-sums-from-a-csv-file-in-python)?

Comment: @roganjosh Did not seem to run correctly.

Comment: Then you should reply to Laurent in that question and ask for clarification. Now you have two questions open for essentially the same thing and nobody knows why it "did not seem to run correctly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going on here:

1)

You are opening up the file without a mode selected.  It does automatically default to read but you may want to be a bit more explicit.

```
with open('mycsvfile', 'r') as csvfile:
.
.
.
```

2)

Since its for an assignment, take a look at the examples provided here in the CSV documentation:

This should get you most of the way:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help Kelvin.

Comment: no problem!  You're welcome